# If $\langle x,u\rangle = \langle x, v\rangle  = \langle x,w\rangle = 0$ then $x=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I'm given that 
$$\begin{align*}
u &= (1, 2, 3)\\
v &= (2, -1, 1)\\
w &= (3, 1, 0)
\end{align*}$$

And I'm asked to verify if $\langle x,u\rangle = \langle x, v\rangle = \langle x,w\rangle = 0$ then $x=0$

I'm not really sure where to start. Logically, isn't it obvious? I know the following: 
$$\begin{align*}
\langle x, u\rangle &= x_{1} + 2x_{2} + 3x_{3}.\\
\langle x, v\rangle &= 2x_{1} - x_{2} + x_{3}\\
\langle x, w\rangle &= 3x_{1} + x_{2} 
\end{align*}$$

But does that get me any where? I feel like I should be thinking about linearly independence and the matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\ 
2 & -1 & 1\\ 
3 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $x$ is orthogonal to $u$, $v$, and $w$, then it is orthogonal to the span of $u$, $v$, and $w$.

A vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $\mathbf{0}$ if and only if it is orthogonal to every vector.

So, the conclusion will follow if and only if $u$, $v$, and $w$ span $\mathbb{R}^3$. if and only if $u$, $v$, and $w$ are linearly independent.

This amounts to the same thing you are doing: the system of linear equations you found has a nontrivial solution if and only if the determinant of your matrix is zero, if and only if the three vectors are **not** linearly independent. So if the vectors are not linearly independent, a nontrivial solution to the system of linear equations (a nonzero element in the nullspace of the matrix) will exhibit an $x$ that is not $\mathbf{0}$ but is orthogonal to each of $u$, $v$, and $w$. If the three vectors **are** linearly independent, then the only solution to the system is $\mathbf{x}=(0,0,0)$, which shows that the desired implication holds.